# Select a range of files after sorting them

Tags: shell, command-line, files, wildcards

One thing I notice slower for me if I switch from using a GUI file manager to CLI is:

In a GUI file manager, I can quickly select a subset of files under a dir by,

- first sorting them according to some order that can consecutively capture the subset of files as many as possible,
- then selecting a consecutive range of files, by holding Shift key and clicking the first and then the last file in the range , and
- then maybe clicking a few files that are not in the consecutive range.

In CLI, what are some ways for us to  select a subset of files as fast as possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

With the `zsh` shell, that's typically done with globbing qualifiers:

```
mv -- *(.om[1,10]) /dir
```

moves the 10 newest non-hidden regular files to `/dir`.

With the completion system (enabled by running `compinstall`), you can also tell `zsh` to expand that list and select which ones to expand using <kbd>Alt-A</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. What about with bash, and to select a consecutive range in the middle (not necessarily the top n files in the sorted result)?

Comment: @Tim, `bash` is about 10 years behind `zsh` in terms of interactive use features. It just about caught up with `tcsh`. If you're going to use the CLI intensively, you should switch to `zsh`.

Comment: " It just about caught up with tcsh", do you mean bash and tcsh are similarly powerful  in terms of interactive use features (but both are less powerful than zsh)?

Comment: @Tim, yes, until the mid 90s, `tcsh` was leading the way. After that, it was `zsh`. `fish` is an interesting newcomer. `bash` has always been far behind.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting, scrolling a bunch, manually selecting a range  and punching holes in the range is natural in a GUI.

One can argue that it is also tedious and error prone.

At the CLI (i.e. a unix shell) you have more powerful means.

When sorting using the filename as key you can use globbing to select a range, e.g.

```
$ rm someprefix*mid*.[0-9]
```

In a sorted list the files beginning with 'someprefix' would show up consecutively - but because we have globbing there is no need to explicitly sort them.

Even with basic globbing syntax can create powerful filters. Shells like zsh provide extensions.

You can also use `find` to combine several critera, e.g.

```
$ find -type f -name 'someprefix*' -not '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

which recursively deletes all files beginning with 'someprefix' but exclude those ending with '.txt'.

`find` provides many options to construct expressions, e.g. logical and/or, grouping, ones to the select based on file size, various timestamps, regular expression applied to the path, etc.

Especially, the possibility to select recursively (the default) is something which speeds up many tasks. Imagine doing instead the same range selection task over and over again for several directories in a GUI file manager ...