# How to select a sub-range of the files in the current directory in a script/on the command line, based on e.g. alphabetical order?

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh, wildcards

In a file manager you can usually select a file, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select another file. Every file in between will be selected.

**I want to do the `bash` / `zsh` equivalent of this.**

I.e: I want to give 2 filenames and have every filename in between (in alphabetical order - the way `ls` outputs them).

I am aware of `? {} *` and other wildcard options, however I want to be able to use this on files with highly scrambled names.

**E.g.:** given the files

```shellsession
$ ls
aoeitoae.txt
oaeistn.txt
oaie.txt
paeoai.txt
sotaoe.txt
```

I would like to give a command like `rm aoeitoae.txt-oaie.txt` and then end up with:

```shellsession
$ ls
paeoai.txt
sotaoe.txt
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Interesting. This is a "feature" that I probably would never find helpful, but I'm surprised it hasn't been mentioned or asked about before.

Comment: maybe it was. but i'm struggling to name this feature concisely to be able to search for it

Comment: if this is a problem you need to solve intereactively more often, using a text user interface file manager like `ranger` or `mc` might make sense :)

Comment: I don't have UNIX at hand right now, but what about `ls -1 | sed -n -e '/first_file/,/last_file/p'`?

Comment: I would use Emacs dired mode :)

Comment: @U.Windl, that's what I'd do for _this specific case_, but remember the usual caveats for filenames containing whitespace (and newlines in particular).

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147673/377345

Comment: My solution using `sed` won't work, but I'll propose a nice one using `ed` instead.

Comment: In this specific example, `rm [a-o]*.txt` would remove the 3 files you want.  Perhaps you could craft a better example, like one where there's an `oab....txt` you don't want to remove, and you don't want to use `rm -i` to manually say yes to all but the last; easy to get that wrong.

Answer (score 10):

This answer focuses on zsh. Most of it can't be done easily in bash.

Many common cases can be done with [wildcards](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators). In particular:

- Everything with a **fixed prefix**: `foo-*`
- Everything with a **fixed prefix followed by one more letter within a range**: `foo[b-m]*` (includes `foobar`, `food`, `foomz1`, but not `fooar` or `foon`)
- **Numbers in a range**: `IMG-<7-42>.*` (includes `IMG-8.PNG` and `IMG-0042.JPG` but not `IMG-77.JPG`)

With [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), there's an easy way to identify a **range, but it requires counting**: `foo*([1,3])` matches the first 3 files listed by `foo*`, whatever they are (or all files if there are fewer than 3). This takes place after whatever sorting is done, for example `foo*(om[1,3])` matches the three most recently modified files whose name starts with `foo`.

You can make zsh figure out the numbers for you. Do it in two steps: first put all the matches in an array, then find the endpoints using the [subscript flags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags) `i` and `I` (also `e` if you want to prevent any wildcard matching): `$a[$a[(i)foo],$a[(I)bar]]` is the part of the array `$a` from the element `foo` to the element `bar` inclusive, and empty if either `foo` or `bar` is not present.

```
a=(*.txt(oL))
# List the files that appear between small.txt and large.txt in a listing by size.
# Note that files that have the same size as one of the bounds may or may not be included.
echo $a[$a[(I)small.txt],$a[(I)large.txt]]
```

So here's a function that implements **exactly the requirements of the question** (except the exact syntax, which can't be done):

```
# Usage: select_range FROM TO WILDCARD_PATTERN
# Sets the array $s to the files matching PATTERN from FROM to TO inclusive.
function select_range {
  if (($# < 2)); then
    echo >&2 "select_range: missing range arguments"
    return 120
  fi
  local from=$1 to=$2
  shift 2
  from=$@[(ie)$from]
  if ((from == 0)); then
    echo >&2 "select_range: not matched: $from"
  fi
  to=$@[(Ie)$to]
  if ((to == 0)); then
    echo >&2 "select_range: not matched: $from"
  fi
  s=($@[$from,$to])
}
```

Usage: `select_range aoeitoae.txt oaie.txt * && rm $s`

The `e` glob qualifier lets you write arbitrary code to filter results, but it already starts getting a little unwieldy. Quoting can be tricky in complex cases; to keep things simple, use `'` as the delimiter (which needs to be quoted with a backslash) and put the filter code in single quotes, meaning the pattern looks like this: `foo-*(e\''code goes here'\')`. (If the quoting gets too complicated, write a function and use the `+` qualifier.) To filter files that come after `aoeitoae.txt` and before `oaie.txt` **in lexicographic order**: `*(e\''! [[ $REPLY < aoeitoae.txt || $REPLY > oaie.txt ]]'\')`.

Note that the comparisons done in the filter don't necessarily use the same order as the wildcard expansion. For example, `foo-*(n)` lists `foo-9` before `foo-10` thanks to the `n` qualifier, but `[[ foo-9 > foo-10 ]]` in a string comparison, and there's no [conditional](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions) operator similar to `>` that compares integer substrings numerically. If you want to do a **string comparison with integer parts sorted numerically**, you can use the `n` [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) for array sorting and check that it keeps the matched name in the middle: `*(ne\''a=(b11r $REPLY f10o); [[ $a[2] == "${${(@n)a}[2]}" ]]'\'))` includes `b101r`, `b11s`, `d1`, `f02o`, …, but not `b9r`, `f011`, …

If you're matching files by date, you can use the `-nt` conditional (note that a file is not newer than itself): `*(ome\''! [[ $REPLY -ot from || $REPLY -nt to ]]'\')` only includes **files modified between** the modification time of `from` and the modification time of `to`, inclusive.

Answer (score 8):

Using a bash function:

```
sfiles ()
(
    # run this in a subshell, so we don't have to care if nullglob/dotglob were enabled or not
    [ $# -eq 0 ] && exit
    
    local nullsep=0
    if [ "$1" = "-0" ]; then
        nullsep=1; shift
    fi
    local first=$1
    shift $(($# -1))
    local last=$1
    local files=( )

    shopt -s nullglob dotglob
    for i in *; do
        # first argument found or array not empty?
        if [ "$i" = "$first" ] || [ "${#files[@]}" -ne 0 ]; then
            files+=( "$i" )
        fi
        # last argument found? break loop
        [ "$i" = "$last" ] && break
    done

    if [ "${#files[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
        [ "$nullsep" -eq 1 ] && 
            printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" ||
            printf '%s\n' "${files[@]@Q}"
    fi
)
```

It outputs all files between the first and the last argument (inclusive).

Examples:

```
$ ls -A
 btjhyyxrlv.txt    otewagahzp.txt       .xxx
 crlcsbzizl.txt    ssffszhdmp.txt      'zdjtgahx q.txt'
 hgiagchkgt.txt   'tt'$'\t''aa.txt'    'zmwik zhur.txt'
 jusupbivit.txt    umikyfucgu.txt      'z otmleqlq.txt'
' kcyigyurc.txt'  ' upvpntdfv.txt'      .zzz
 kfthnpgrxm.txt   'uu'$'\t\t''aa.txt'
 lgzsmquxwj.txt    wlwexgzohs.txt
```

```
$ sfiles c* k*
'crlcsbzizl.txt'
'hgiagchkgt.txt'
'jusupbivit.txt'
' kcyigyurc.txt'
'kfthnpgrxm.txt'
```

```
$ sfiles .xxx .zzz
'.xxx'
'zdjtgahx q.txt'
'zmwik zhur.txt'
'z otmleqlq.txt'
'.zzz'
```

```
$ LC_ALL=C sfiles .xxx .zzz
'.xxx'
'.zzz'
```

Wrong order, this one returns nothing:

```
$ sfiles .zzz .xxx
```

Remove selected files with `xargs`:

```
$ sfiles .xxx .zzz | xargs rm
```

For filenames with tabs or newlines, add option `-0` as first argument for null-separated output without bash quoting.

```
$ sfiles -0 tt* uu* | xargs -0 ls
'tt'$'\t''aa.txt'  ' upvpntdfv.txt'
 umikyfucgu.txt    'uu'$'\t\t''aa.txt'
```

Comment: I like the `-0` approach! directly recommending that in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: This approach is also good if the split-points don't necessarily exist, because we can use `[[ <` to test for inclusion.

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own shell function that does that for you: get a list of all files, and remove all before the first file name, and all after the second. Roughly, in zsh, because I think this will be more annoying in bash:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/zsh
filerange() {
  # variable "reply" is an array
  typeset -ag reply
  reply=("$1")
  # don't get upset if nothing matches
  setopt nullglob

  # get a complete list of candidate files
  #allfiles=*(^/^on) 
  #         ^--------- *   glob
  #          ^----^--- (…) glob modifiers within parentheses
  #           ^------- ^   invert match
  #            ^------ /   match directories (inverted: match all *but* dirs)
  #             ^----- ^   invert sort order (uninvert the above inversion)
  #              ^---- o   order by:
  #               ^--- n    character values of name
  for fname in *(on^/); do
    [[ ( "$2" > "${fname}" && "${fname}" > "$1" ) ]] \
    && reply+=("${fname}")
  done
  reply+=("$2")
}
```

That gives you a nice and "safe" array in `$reply` which you can well use e.g. in `for`:

```bash
# prepare a test dir
mkdir /tmp/testdir
cd /tmp/testdir
sudo mknod blockdev b 1 1
sudo mknod chardev c 1 1
mkdir dir
mkfifo fifo
touch file
touch "file with spaces"
touch "file with\nnewlines"
touch "last file"
touch "ok one more file"
ln -s blockdev symlink

# This will look funny, because there's a file name with a new line in there
echo *

# Let's try this:
filerange chardev "last file"
# We're expecting to get all files from (incl) chardev to (incl) last file,
# but not `dir`, as that's a directory
for f in ${reply}; do;
  echo "entry: ${f}"
done
```

Of course, if you just want to print these files (e.g., for `parallel` or `xargs`), writing a function that takes an optional `-0` as Freddy's [excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/735676/106650) illustrates is a great choice! That function would be pretty barebone: it could just call `filerange` and deal with the `$reply` from that in a `printf`'ing `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious way would be

```
ls | sed -n -e "/$first/,/$last/p" | xargs rm
```

with `$first` and `$last` being regular expressions to match the first and last files to process:

```
first='^aoeitoae\.txt$'
last='^oaie\.txt$'
```

Of course, this is risky for a couple of reasons - firstly, `ls` implementations have differing behaviour for names containing non-printing characters, and `xargs` will do the Wrong Thing with names containing newline.

If we're using GNU tools, we can solve this by using `\0` as the separator, with `sed -z` and `xargs -0`:

```
printf '%s\0' * | sed -zn -e "/$first/,/$last/p" | xargs -0r rm
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer, but I wanted to mention that `awk` has a nice range operator that could be used:

```
$ ls | awk '/^aoeitoae\.txt$/,/^oaie\.txt$/ { print }'
aoeitoae.txt
oaeistn.txt
oaie.txt
```

The `awk` code prints input lines, starting with the first one that matches the first regular expression and ending with the first one after that which matches the second regex.

Beware that the matches use regular expressions and that their is no quoting whatsoever in this example, so this might lead to unexpected results with whitespace or other strange characters in filenames.

And *maybe* you want to try using a text-based file manager like [Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org/).

Comment: While this is true, it still has the problem of [parsing the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/377345), which - as you probably know - poses the danger of filename pitfalls.

Answer (score 2):

This version can give you files with *starting characters* in a range:

```bash
filerange() {
    (
        local OPTARG OPTIND
        local fmt='%s\n'
        while getopts :0 opt; do
            [[ $opt == '0' ]] && fmt='%s\0'
        done
        shift $((OPTIND - 1))

        local pattern="[$1-$2]*"
        shopt -s nocasematch
        shopt -s nullglob
        for f in *; do 
            if [[ $f == $pattern ]]; then
                printf "$fmt" "$f"
            fi
        done
    )
}
```

And you'd use it like

```bash
filerange e m
filerange -0 e m | xargs -0 rm -i
```

Remove `shopt -s nocasematch` if you don't want case insensitivity.

I suspect this isn't what you're after since it's not providing "from *this* file to *that* file" precision.

Comment: I believe from this you can whip out easily an awk solution that would check each filename is within the 2 "limit filenames" ? `( var <= file1 && var >= file2 )` (lexicographically) ? the awk itself would need to be maybe cast with the correct LC_ALL=foo or LC_COLLATE=foo  (I can't do this right now, and I also know I would most probably end up with a less optimal solution than you would)

Comment: But this functionality is already in bash and zsh, isn't it? `rm [e-m]*`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, it seems that given your comparison to the graphical File Manager you might be interested in having a bit of interactivity - and also in turn, having a bit more general solution that applies to a different set of files.

The extra benefit is also that the code is fairly simple. All you need is the `vipe` pipe editor utility - that comes in `moreutils` package in most distributions.

DISCLAIMER: Before you move on to this, please be aware that this solution is not a perfect one - if your filenames contain characters such as line breaks, they will result in separate lines in your editor, which can result in errors and/or removing the files you don't want. Make sure you have no such files first.

What you will need to do, is to run the following command, and edit the list in the editor that pops up, so that it contains only the files that you want to remove.

`$ ls | vipe | while read; do rm "$REPLY"; done`

If you don't like the editor that pops up with `vipe`, you can change the EDITOR/VISUAL variable beforehand (VISUAL takes precedence):

`$ EDITOR=nano`

Answer (score 0):

This solution maybe considered somewhat ugly, but it works:

```sh
(T=$(mktemp -u) && mkfifo "$T" && (ls -1 >"$T" & sleep 1) && echo '/^first_pattern$/,/^last_pattern$/p' | ed -s "$T" && rm "$T")
```

The `sleep 1` isn't an elegant solution to deal with the race condition that `ed` might start before the FIFO had been created, but anyway:

- Write the directory contents to a temporary FIFO, one filename per line.
  As the FIFO may block the writer, do it asynchronously (in background).
- Use `ed` to read from the FIFO, outputting the lines from `first_pattern` matching first until (and including) `last_pattern` matching first.

For safety's sake I did not place `rm $(...)` around the command.
So if you really want it, ...

This pattern is known to fail if the lines (read: filenames) contain spaces or other unusual characters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned the Shift-click/select workflow: If you are indeed interested in interactively choosing a set of files to pipe to a next stage, you can use `fzf`.

For example, let's say you have 4 files - and you want to select some to delete. To make it more interesting, let's have spaces inside filenames:

```
$ mkdir a
$ cd a
$ touch a b c 'd e'  # Create 4 files, one containing spaces in its name
$ ls -l
... (see screenshot below)
$ ls | fzf -m --print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

This screen will pop up:

[image: Spawning fzf]

And you can then select with the TAB key, and de-select with Shift-TAB, the files you want to pass to fzf's stdout:

[image: Choosing files]

Every time you hit TAB, the file will get a ">" marker on its left. De-select with Shift-TAB. You can navigate the list with fuzzy finding (what the acronym 'fzf' stands for) so feel free to type letters from the file(s) you want to jump to.

When you are satisfied, hit ENTER.

[image: Files passed to rm]

As you can see, the list of files was emitted to stdout, using null terminators to separate them (option `--print0`). The next part of the pipeline was `xargs` - which, due to the `-0` option splitted the input back into separate filenames, and passed each one of them to `rm`. Our two selected files were thus removed.

The use of null separators guarantees that the pipeline will work no matter what crazy characters may exist in your filenames (spaces, commas, newlines, whatever).

Hope this helps.